# Error validating an array of radio buttons in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am fetching rows from the database. Each row has 2 radio buttons.At least, one button must be selected in each row.  I am having issues validating all rows. My present validation only works for one row.

My view:

```
@foreach($items as $item)                 
    <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
                <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">

                <input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}]" value="2"> Approve
                <input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}]" value="6"> Decline
            </div>
        </td>    
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
</form>
```

My Controller

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), 
        ['item_id' => 'required',
        'item_id.*' => 'required'], ['item_id.required' => 'Either approve or decline all items']
    );
    if($validator->fails()){
        return back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
        //return 'error';
    }else{
        echo "true";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

What is your laravel version ?

You juste have to validate like this :

```
'item_id' => 'required'
```

No need to put any stars